# How do you constraint a RAILS 4 route to exclude all paths with integers in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am wanting to route the main site and exclude paths with digits in them (like the account id).

So for example, I want to constraint a url like domain.com/about_us or domain.com/signup/plan/1
BUT exclude all paths that start with a integer, like domain.com/1234573/user/3 or domain.com/123456

I have the following code but I get "No route matches [GET] '/signup'" when going to any of the constraint urls like domain.com/signup. I get the homepage just fine (domain.com).

```
class MainSite
  # Match only non account pages
  # urls like domain.com/signup
  # BUT NOT like domain.com/2342342
  def self.matches?(request)
    not request.path =~ %r{\A\/\D}
  end
end

Myapp::Application.routes.draw do

devise_for :app_admins
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/app_admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

  # Routes for the public site
  constraints MainSite do
    # Homepage
    get '/' => "content#index"
    get '/signup' => 'accounts#plans', :as => 'plans'
    ....
  end

  root :to => "accounts#dashboard"
  devise_for :users
...
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see what I did wrong... It was in my regex. I had `\D` instead of `\d`. I was excluding all numbers. Hah!

Answer (score 0):

I have an actual answer:

Put the route that you don't want above the one you do in routes.rb, and send it to a handler that redirects to home or similar.